# Dell Inspiron 14r Display Problem- Tried Everything

Tags: 13.10, dell, brightness

I know there are a million posts about this, but I have been on this forum for hours and haven't found a solution to my problem.  Like many people, my brightness keys don't work and I am looking for a different way to adjust my brightness.  I have tried

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness
```

which actually does something but really only jacks up my contrast.
I have tried

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

and

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=FF
```

and nothing happened at all.

I have also tried the app xbacklight which didn't do anything and fiddling with dconf-editor, which I don't think will be able to solve my problem.

I am very new to Ubuntu so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of these two should work

Open your terminal by pressint `ctrl+alt+t` and type:

`echo 7 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

If it is not working then tyep this command in terminal

`sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`[ENTER]

and then type : `800000`

(or any other value less than 3316785, in my case. Lower value of low brightness and higher value for more brightness).

(2nd one worked for me as I am using Acer Aspire 5738 laptop).

Comment: I am very new to Linux.  I am not sure exactly what you mean or what those commands are supposed to do...would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer.